# Change python3 command directory in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, shell

**Problem:**
I am using Mac Catalina 10.15. I know that Catalina installed Python 2.7 already and I installed Python 3.7.3. Then I also installed Anaconda which contained Conda, Python 3.7.3. Now I have 3 Pythons:

A. /usr/bin/python   -> python 2.7
B. /usr/bin/python3  -> python 3.7.3
C. /Users/david/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python -> python 3.7.6

When I type "python3" in terminal it will run B. But I want to change "python3" command to open C.

**What I tried:**
I found "/Users/david/.bash_profile" and added

```
alias python3="/Users/david/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python"
```

at end of the file but "python3" still opens B. How can I open Anaconda Python by typing "python3" in the terminal?

Comment: David, have you tried `$ source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Hello Noah, you are correct. It works. Thank you very much. End this post plz.

Comment: Read my answer if you want it to load your aliases automatically every new session :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have not so already, try running:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

That will load all your settings for the current terminal session. However, this will not load automatically when you start a new terminal session. For this to happen, you first need to know what shell you are running.
Run:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

If it returns `/bin/zsh` like mine does(which it should since this is MacOS Catalina), you must copy your alias to the bottom of `~/.zshrc`. Then your alias will automatically be loaded when you start a new terminal session.
If for some reason `echo $SHELL` returns something other than `/bin/zsh`, run:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

which will change your shell to `zsh`. Then your alias settings in `~/.zshrc` will be loaded in every new terminal session.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have ~/.zshrc so I add a file under /Users/david/. It works.

Comment: No. I noticed that I am not the default shell and changed back to zsh, just one hour before I read your answer. I don't know when and how I change to that shell. But anyway I changed back.